# format dateTime to a specified format using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

`fn:current-dateTime() + xs:yearMonthDuration('-P1M')`, is there any way I can format this result to `yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss` using xslt?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot format a date using XPath, but you can do so using XSLT: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#contents